# enumerate days of week in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is anybody to know how to enumerate all week's days in T-SQL, so that we have in the ouput a string like: 'Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, ...'

Comment: That's not a very long string, and the days of the week are not likely to change: why not just `select 'Sunday, Monday Tuesday..'`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: this may be culture dependent.

Comment: @Qaussnoi it may be indeed; there could be a lot of reasons that a hard-coded string won't work, but apros doesn't mention any in the question.. so I asked.

Comment: @Qaussnoi is right. This is a dependence on culture in my case

Comment: @cyberkiwi  In my case it's fit, because of SQL Server 2005, 2008

Comment: dependent on culture = installing in different regions around the world? will DATEFIRST setting matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight select that will work with any `SET DATEFIRST` setting

```
select
    datename(dw,   6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 1+6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 2+6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 3+6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 4+6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 5+6-@@datefirst) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 6+6-@@datefirst)
```

If you don't care about region (Monday or Sunday as first day of week), then just

```
select
    datename(dw, 0) + ', ' + datename(dw, 1) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 2) + ', ' + datename(dw, 3) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 4) + ', ' + datename(dw, 5) + ', ' +
    datename(dw, 6) + ', '
```

It will perform much better than going through CTE and will also work in 2000 should you ever need it.

Comment: I will prefer you answer, because of my intension to use this query in a function which can be called many times due to a big amount of data. So, recursion, that was suggested by @Quassnoi, is not my choice here. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The first script does depend on `@@datefirst` and very curiously so, but it will cease doing that after replacing `...-@@datefirst` with `...+@@datefirst`.

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH    week (dn) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  dn + 1
        FROM    week
        WHERE   dn < 7
        )
SELECT  DATENAME(dw, dn + 5) 
FROM    week
```

Replace `dn + 5` with `dn + 6` if your week starts from `Monday`.

If you need a single comma separated string instead of a set, use this:

```
WITH    week (dn, dname) AS
        (
        SELECT  1, CAST(DATENAME(dw, 6) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  dn + 1, dname + ', ' + DATENAME(dw, dn + 6)
        FROM    week
        WHERE   dn < 7
        )
SELECT  dname
FROM    week
WHERE   dn = 7
```

Comment: It seems that your enumeration order will depend on the current day, isn't it? I mean that today it will begin from Sunday, tommorow from Monday etc..

Comment: @apros: no it won't. `dn` here are constant numbers from `1` to `7` and when used in `DATENAME` are implicitly cast to constant dates (`1900-01-02` to `1900-01-08`).

Comment: thanks, for explanation. I just was confused with existed depends on digits

Comment: that's a bit harsh - it's a solution after all (even if using a sledgehammer)

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Never gave an answer before bad enough to be called stupid but good enough not to deserve a downvote!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Quassnoi, but in my case, I need to take into account performance also.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest means is to statically define the comma separated list. I don't know if `SET DATEFIRST` affects only the database -- if it's the entire instance, I would really hesitate to use SET DATEFIRST.

Rather than using recursion, you can use the values from MASTER..SPT_VALUES, and a combination of the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and [FOR XML PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx) functions (Caveat: SQL Server 2005+):

### Week starting on Sunday:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + x.wkday_name 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(dw, t.number) AS wkday_name, 
                             t.number
                        FROM MASTER.dbo.SPT_VALUES t
                       WHERE t.number BETWEEN -1 AND 5) x
                    ORDER BY x.number
                     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
```

### Week starting on Monday:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + x.wkday_name 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(dw, t.number) AS wkday_name, 
                             t.number
                        FROM MASTER.dbo.SPT_VALUES t
                       WHERE t.number BETWEEN 0 AND 6) x
                    ORDER BY x.number
                     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
```

### Comparison:

The statically defined list won't return a query plan for me on SQL Server 2005.  Quassnoi's recursion example on 2005 has a subtree cost of 0.0000072; SPT_VALUES has a subtree cost of 0.0158108.  So the recursive approach is appears more efficient than SPT_VALUES -- possibly due to the very small size?